# Add prefix string to each value of a flat array

Tags: php, arrays, replace, prefix, prepend

What is the best way to add a specific value or values to an array?

```
<?php
$myarray = array("test", "test2", "test3");
$myarray = array_addstuff($myarray, " ");
var_dump($myarray);
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) " test"
  [1]=>
  string(6) " test2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) " test3"
}
```

You could do so like this:

```
function array_addstuff($a, $i) {
    foreach ($a as &$e)
        $e = $i . $e;
    return $a;
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a faster way, or if this function is built-in.

Comment: take a look at my answer, there is no a faster way, there is indeed a built in function, but for this implementation is proved to be slower

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In the case that you're using a PHP version >= 5.3:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key) { $value .= 'd'; } );
```

Comment: whats the & before the $value for?

Comment: @GDY: it means you're passing this parameter by reference and not by value (default behaviour)
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Technically, you're adding a suffix, not a prefix. Is there a more succinct way to do a prefix in the anonymous function besides `$value = ' ' . $value;`?

Comment: Like this one! Thank you.

Answer (score 32):

Use [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$array = array_map(function($value) { return ' '.$value; }, $array);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have the overhead of creating a whole new array?

Answer (score 14):

Below code will add "prefix_" as a prefix to each element value:

```
$myarray = array("test", "test2", "test3");    
$prefixed_array = preg_filter('/^/', 'prefix_', $myarray);
```

Output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => prefix_test [1] => prefix_test2 [2] => prefix_test3 )
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. As you have used variable names and literals which have no correspondence with the question, that is the least you could do.

Comment: What I have to add prefix at start and end of value?

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). In PHP 5.3 you can use an anonymous to define that callback. Because you want to modify the actual array, you have to specify the first parameter of the callback as pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 0):

PHP already has a native function to replace your `array_addstuff()` function and it doesn't need regex --`substr_replace()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0rQAs))

```
$myarray = ["test", "test2", "test3"];

var_export(
    substr_replace($myarray, ' ', 0, 0)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => ' test',
  1 => ' test2',
  2 => ' test3',
)
```