# Array to string conversion with array_walk in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-walk

I am tried to add the same string to every array value.
I tried to use `array_walk()` like I read it on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535862/3751899).

But I get: Notice: Array to string conversion

I have also tried to use `array_map()`, but I get same error notice.

**working code**

```
if ($voice->getValue() === Voice::Passive) {
    array_walk($aller_form, function(&$value, $key) { $value .= ' être'; });
    $aller_form = [
        Mood::Indicatif => [
            Tense::Futur_compose => [
                Person::FirstPersonSingular => 'vais être',
                Person::SecondPersonSingular => 'vas être',
                Person::ThirdPersonSingular => 'va être',
                Person::FirstPersonPlural => 'allons être',
                Person::SecondPersonPlural => 'allez être',
                Person::ThirdPersonPlural => 'vont être'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}  
return $aller_form[$mood->getValue()][$tense->getValue()][$person->getValue()];
```

**not working code**

```
if ($voice->getValue() === Voice::Passive) {
    array_walk($aller_form, function(&$value, $key) { $value .= ' être'; });            
} 
return $aller_form[$mood->getValue()][$tense->getValue()][$person->getValue()];
```

**EDIT:**

The complete error log:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in  on line 2
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'futur_compose' on line 4
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'firstPersonSingular'  on line 4

(I see 6 times this three error lines for every Person once)

Comment: What is the output of: `print_r($aller_form);`? Also your working and not working code line are exactly the same

Comment: SHOW us the FULL error message and identify the exact line of code in your script that is identified on the error message ( theres a line number in the error ) It would also be useful to know what `$voise` is and what `VOICE::` and the 2 data types in the comparision, but I guess if you look for this information **the answer to the question will become obvious**

Comment: @Rizier123 The output of `print_r($aller_form);` is `Array ( [0] => vais [1] => vas [2] => va [3] => allons [4] => allez [5] => vont )`